# Choose which factor levels to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm wondering what the best way is to eliminate certain factors from a plot in ggplot.

I have data that looks something like:

```
Group    Time    Freq
A        1       5000
B        1       70
C        1       60
...
```

I'm then using `geom_path` to plot how these frequencies change over time.

For all of the time periods, group A has far more observations than the other groups, so I'd like to create some graphs that do not include group A.

I'm wondering what the best way to do that is. Is there something I can pass to `ggplot`?

Comment: You could use `df[df$Group!="A",]` as your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing is to filter the dataframe:

```
df[df$Group != "A",]
```

Or

```
subset(df, group!="A")
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me, but it turns out it was a different bug.

Thank you!